# Using test support code from an ember addon

Tags: ember.js

I have several ember apps which use a common shared ember-cli addon. This addon has common code like models, navigation etc. I also want this addon to provide common test support code like test helpers, factories to the ember apps. However if I remove `tests` from `.npmignore` in the addon, then the test resources gets built with the ember app.

Is there a way to use the addon in an ember app, but strip the addon's `tests` folder on build? Or perhaps there is a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Common code can go to the addon's `test-support` folder. That folder would automatically get merged into the app's `tests` folder.

This is mentioned here - https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-project-structure